# How to disable the Qt Wayland module during QT build?

Tags: qt, qtwayland

I am trying to build Qt on my *raspberry pi* with *jessie* on it.

The configure option that I have provided are as below for my build:

```
./configure -v -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g''+ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/ -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -qt-pcre -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5
```

However, I am getting the below error pertaining to QtWayland ...

```
Project ERROR: wayland-client development package not found
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'sub-brcm-egl-install_subtargets' failed
make[5]: *** [sub-brcm-egl-install_subtargets] Error 3
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/packages/qt5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtwayland/src/plugins/hardwareintegration/client'
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'sub-client-install_subtargets' failed
make[4]: *** [sub-client-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/packages/qt5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtwayland/src/plugins/hardwareintegration'
Makefile:81: recipe for target 'sub-hardwareintegration-install_subtargets' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-hardwareintegration-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/packages/qt5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtwayland/src/plugins'
Makefile:107: recipe for target 'sub-plugins-install_subtargets' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/packages/qt5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtwayland/src'
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'sub-src-install_subtargets' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/packages/qt5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtwayland'
Makefile:737: recipe for target 'module-qtwayland-install_subtargets' failed
make: *** [module-qtwayland-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

Is there any way that I can disable the QtWayland option during Qt build?

Answer (score 14):

You can skip it while doing configure

./configure **-skip wayland**.